# Laravel development: Implication when creating MySQL database manually

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm in the process of building a Laravel application and I started with the database design. I implemented this directly on the commandline (`mysql`).

Now, I have this lingering concern as for what this could lead to in the coming development cycles.

I do know that I miss out on the version control as well as the rollback of database structure changes that `php artisan` provides.

- Are there other Laravel/PHP specific aspects I should keep in mind?
- Would you (Laravel developer), recommend that I recreate the entire database structure using `php artisan make:migration`?

I could really use your input based on this situation of Laravel/PHP development in many cycles without database migration control?

Please advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, In my opinion you should go for using `migrations`. Migrations provide a great interface to change database structure in version controlled manner.

For instance, If in future you have to move from `mysql` to some other database system. Following your current approach your would have to create all the db structures according to the new system.

While using migrations, you just have to update a config file for the db driver. And you are done.

Comment: Thanks for your input, that makes sense. So one consideration is essentially the possible change of RDBMS.

Comment: Yes, the second one for me is ease of moving between different versions of your db at any given point. And ofcourse, I find migration files more readable.